# inserting in mysqli is not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to get data from one table and inserting it in another table.
But the problem is that it is not inserting.
Here is my code

```
$query = "SELECT id,pname,medicin FROM logpn WHERE id = '$login_session'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbhandle,$query);
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
      $id = $row['id'];
      $pname = $row['pname'];
      $med = $row['medicin'];}



     if (isset($_POST['button1'])) {
        mysqli_query($dbhandle,"INSERT INTO medicin_refill (id, pname, medicin) VALUES ('$id', '$pname', '$med')") or die(mysqli_error($dbhandle));
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong??

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: I don't get any errors

Comment: add HTML part. in the question

Comment: Can you check the loginsession variable has value

Comment: loginsession I checked it has a value

Comment: the html part is this `<button id="button1"class="btn btn-danger">Request Refilling</button>`

Comment: Ur getting the data from the select statement

Comment: Add a `name="button1"` in your html

Comment: yes from the select statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try `VALUES ($id,[...]` instead of `VALUES ('$id',[...]` because the `$id` shouldn't be a string.